# Could there be a list of selected educative questions from MSE to accompany a learner working through baby Rudin?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I am a learner of mathematics currently on undergraduate level, and this website (MSE) is very helpful also amazing to me. So this is my humble wish:

Could there be a list of selected educative questions from MSE to accompany a learner working through *baby Rudin* (or any famous undergraduate textbook)?

Thanks in advance for any comment or answer! Also sorry if this was asked before.

**Edit1:** After reading the first 2 answers....I find that I did not notice mustering volunteer "senior users" will be a problem. In [Reddit r/AskDocs/](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskDocs/) there are verified medical professionals voluntarily answer medical questions on internet! Also see my comments I believe such list will not be organized/edited by "senior users" to be only a solutions manual.

Comment: Who are "we", and what do you mean by "keeping a list"? Offline?

Comment: @mrf: If such list will possibly exist I believe (1) it's link may probably be put in the side bar and (2) it should be organized/edited by very senior users...Maybe I should rephrase this post now.

Comment: There were some related older discussion. For example: [Creating a solutions manual within a single math.SE question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11971/creating-a-solutions-manual-within-a-single-math-se-question) and [About collections of questions at SE which are “solution manuals” to some book](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12016/about-collections-of-questions-at-se-which-are-solution-manuals-to-some-book) and [“Hint book” for arbitrary books (Rudin, Hungerford, etc.)?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11703)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: If such list will possibly exist I believe (3) it will not be organized/edited (by senior users) to be a solutions manual but help providing more complementary contents/exercises to the (usually terse) textbook. For example, *baby Rudin* constructed $\mathbb{R}$ by Dedekind cut and did not prove the uniqueness of the complete ordered field, hence I believe this MSE post http://math.stackexchange.com/q/11923/275935 will be a treasure to those want to learn more thoroughly.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Also for example, there are three definitions of $\limsup$ from different famous textbooks (*baby Rudin*, *Apostol*, and Terence Tao's *Analysis I*), and I believe it would be great to see a post proving or giving hints to prove they are all equivalent.

(BTW there is already a solutions manual for *baby Rudin* here http://minds.wisconsin.edu/handle/1793/67009 so there is no need to create another solutions manual in MSE.)

Comment: Since you wrote that you plan to read Rudin and also your posts on the main show that you are interested in calculus and analysis, I wanted to let you know about existence of [Calculus and analysis room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/14150/2015/10/16) in chat. Admittedly, it was rather inactive so far. But the more people know about it, the bigger chance that this can change.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Thank you!! In this two semesters I am attending an undergraduate analysis class working through Marsden's *Elementary Classical Analysis*. I had found that Freenode's Math IRC channel is helpful for learning. I will try the chat rooms in MSE if further or similar help is needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not among the core purposes of the site to provide such lists. I therefore oppose any effort to try and compose it within Mathematics.SE itself.

On the other hand, I can see the merit of having a resource composed of insightful Question/Answer pairs based on a commonly used mathematics textbook like baby Rudin.

Thus, provided you can muster a set of "senior users" actually willing to create and curate such a "list", I'd say there is potential for a blog with this theme. Such a blog might help expose Maths.SE as a useful repository of mathematical knowledge, aiding in its success.

But as said, part of the success of this site is in its focus: it's not, and never will be, a vehicle to teach entire areas of mathematics -- it's just a place where concrete mathematics questions are asked and answered.

Answer (score 4):

I like the idea; anything that brings more structure to the raging ocean of questions is a bonus. A while back I put together a list of [frequent calculus questions](https://mathindex.wordpress.com/) and used it many times since for locating duplicates.

Some caveats:

- It wouldn't be integrated with the site, you'll have to put it elsewhere (e.g., I used WordPress).
- You'll have to do it yourself; don't expect there to be "very senior users" with nothing better to do.